# Uploading 30,000 posts into Wordpress without causing an XML-RPC crash

Tags: php, python, wordpress, xml-rpc

I have about 30,000 very short posts to make in Wordpress. I built them using a SQLlite database and python script, and was uploading them via the wordpress_xmlrpc library in python. But my site goes down after 100-200 posts, because the server thinks this is a DoS attack.

My server is a linux box to which I have SSH access. I'm looking for a way to easily upload the posts into Wordpress more directly, say by interacting directly with its database, or using a local process that happens directly on the server. Can anyone offer any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried restoring directly the SQL database with the posts you want to add?

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to do the same by interacting directly with the database through Python script and it worked like a charm for me. I was using MySQL database.

For this you need to ssh into the server where Wordpress site and your database is hosted. And run the following script there:

> Perquisite to run this script:
>
> a. All the posts should be in different files within a single
>   directory.
>
> b. Each file should contain post title in first line and post content
>   in rest of the lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb
import fnmatch
import os

#List to contain all the post files
my_match = []

#Gather post files in above list
for file in os.listdir("<path of the directory where post files remains>"):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '.*'):
        print(file)
        continue
    my_match.append(file)

print my_match

#Make database connection
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost", user="<username>", passwd="<password>", db="<database name>")

x = conn.cursor()
print x

for fl in my_match:
     new_file = "<path to the directory where post files remains>/" + fl
with open(new_file) as f:
    heading = f.readline().strip()
    content = f.read()


print heading
url = heading.replace(" ", "-")

print url

#try db query, change according to your database and tables
try:
    x.execute("""INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author, post_date, post_content, post_title, post_name) VALUES (3, "2017-03-28 20:24:12", %s, %s, %s)""",(content, heading, url))
    conn.commit()
    print "Done! :)"
except:
    conn.rollback()
    print "Oops, not done :("

conn.close()
```

Comment: I will try this straight away and get back to you if it works. Thanks!!

Comment: Rohini, I'm curious...there are a lot of other fields in the sql database for posts...did you use a "rebuild database" feature from your Wordpress control panel to update all these?

Comment: No AstroBen, All other fields of `wp_posts` table can be NULL or have their default value set. Thats why I have not put any value for them and also they were not of my use.

Answer (score 0):

Found another way, in case anyone else stumbles on this. Dump all the posts to a csv file and use a "csv to post" widget. I'm using Ultimate CSV Importer Free. Very simple.

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as the answer if it answered the question for you. This will help future visitors. Thanks!